# assign passed object to member object in constructor

Tags: c++

for some reason I can´t achieve this.

```
Line::Line(const Pixel &aStart, const Pixel &aEnd){
  start = aStart;
  end = aEnd;
}
```

the Line class:

```
class Line : public Vertex{
public:
  Line(const Pixel &start, const Pixel &end);
  Pixel getStart();
  Pixel getEnd();
private:
  Pixel start;
  Pixel end;
};
```

g++ tells me

> error: no matching function for call to ‘Pixel::Pixel()’
>   note: candidates are:
>
> ```
> - Pixel::Pixel(int, int, int, int, int)
> - Pixel::Pixel(int, int)
> - Pixel::Pixel(const Pixel&)//not implemented by me, some sort of default constructor?
> ```

I thought actually Im using the last constructor, but something doesnt work. Any help much appreciated.

EDIT: The Pixel Class:

```
class Pixel{
public:
  Pixel(int x, int y);
  Pixel(int red, int green, int blue, int x, int y);
  void setRed(int red);
  void setGreen(int green);
  void setBlue(int blue);
  void setColor(int r, int g, int b);
  int getRed();
  int getGreen();
  int getBlue();
  bool isChanged();
  int getX();
  int getY();
private:
  int red;
  int green;
  int blue;
  int x;
  int y;
  bool hasBeenChanged;
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Line` members of type `Pixel`, `start` and `end`, will be default constructed before the constructor of `Line` runs and sets them to the objects passed in as arguments. It seems that your `Pixel` class doesn't have a default constructor (because giving any user-defined constructor will stop the compiler from giving you an implicit default constructor). You need to make use of a constructor member initialization list:

```
Line::Line(const Pixel &aStart, const Pixel &aEnd)
  : start(aStart), end(aEnd)
{ }
```

This initialises `start` and `end` with `aStart` and `aEnd` respectively, bypassing the default construction that would normally occur.

Comment: The Compiler gives me this now. I google it but couldnt find a solution yet: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "vtable for Line", referenced from:
      Line::Line(Pixel const&, Pixel const&)in ccMJBw1V.o
      Line::Line(Pixel const&, Pixel const&)in ccMJBw1V.o

Comment: ok the problem comes from the Line class is deriving from an abstract class. anyway, this particular problem is solved for now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Because you declare this

```
Pixel::Pixel(int, int, int, int, int) 

Pixel::Pixel(int, int)
```

the compiler doesn't generate a default constrcutor, or a constructor exists with arguements having default values.

```
Pixel start;
Pixel end;
```

These require a default constructor. It doesn't find one, hence the compiler complains. You current code requires the default constructors.

And as a good practice use the initialization list, which wouldn't ask the arguements to default constructed.

```
Line::Line(const Pixel &aStart, const Pixel &aEnd):start(aStart), end(aEnd){}
```

Comment: I'm not the down voter, but since the asker writes over the default constructed `Pixel` objects, he/she probably doesn't care much for `Pixel` having a default constructor (at least, for now).

Comment: I didnt downvote, but the compiler suggests me to use this Pixel::Pixel(const Pixel&) constructor even tho it´s not implemented, that confuses me.

Comment: @dan - That is the copy constructor, you are looking for. How is your Pixel class implemented ? Is it defined by you or from a outside library ?

Comment: it´s defined by me. I add the class definition.